# Can one extend a Thai 30-day visa-free stamp any time before the stamp's expiration or can one extend it only when close to the expiration?

Tags: visas, thailand, passport-stamps, visa-extensions

I read on https://www.dontworryjusttravel.com/asiapacific/thailand/thailand-60-day-tourist-visa/#How_to_extend_your_stay_for_30_more_days_without_getting_a_Thailand_tourist_visa:

> Can I extend my tourist visa in Thailand? If you entered Thailand and received a 30 day stamp in your passport (this is called a 30 day visa exemption) – you can also extend a 60 day tourist visa by 30 days to a total of 90 days for the same fee – you can extend this stamp a further 30 days at any Thailand immigration centre for a fee of 1900 Baht.

Can one extend one's 30-day visa-free stamp any time before the stamp's expiration one wants or can one extend it only when close to the expiration? For example, can one extend the 30-day visa-free stamp just the day after getting the stamp when entering Thailand?

Comment: what date did you enter thailand?  What country is your passport from?

Comment: @JonGrah French citizen. I entered Thailand about 10 days ago, but curious to know from when one can apply for the extension.

Comment: side question:  how were you allowed into the country, considering the current bio-political landscape caused by covid-19.  Especially from France.   Where/how did you arrive?  what was it like passing through immigration.

Comment: @JonGrah Arrived before border closure. Nobody even checked my temperature at the airport and masks weren't compulsory in the plane/airport. I first was aiming to go to Taipei but my passport was too wet for it. https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/155092/1810 thanks for the answer by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally between 15-30 days of the extension expiration date, you apply for the extension.   Some offices will turn you away if they deem it is too early.   But 15-30 days is the normal time.

For a 1 year extension of stay, I've seen up to 45 days early as being acceptable.