# Slight stain on passport

Tags: passports

Can someone please help, I’m due to fly to Spain in 3 weeks, and I’ve just pulled out my passport out of my draw and noticed a make up stain on the page above my bio data page, is this going to be a issue?
Thanks everyone [image]

Comment: If they are looking for an excuse to deny you passage these things can and do happen, but you should be fine most of the time, I think.

Answer (score 4):

If that is the only damage, probably not.

If the photo and all identification markers on the passport are still in good working order, I would imagine you will be OK.

People mishandle passport all the time, get them wet, get them dirty ...

If unsure, go get a new passport ASAP, and ask (**and pay**) for express delivery..

Comment: @meg26 - If you are planning to fly to Spain from the US, that might be the bigger concern.

Comment: I’m flying from the uk so fingers crossed, I’ve spoken to the passport office and they just told me to do what I think but due to the current climate I wouldn’t get a new one in time because they don’t have a fast track service to offer

Answer (score 0):

You can look at these [3 options](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/155099/1810) suggested by [Anish Sheela](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/67804/anish-sheela) in case you fear your passport may get denied, though I agree with Max that it is very unlikely.

Anish's 3 options (which may or may not be available):

> 1. Get a [one-time travel document](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Travel_document&oldid=964266113#Laissez-passer_and_emergency_passports) from your embassy [which is typically faster than obtaining a new passport].
> 2. Sign indemnity form saying that you accept personal responsibility to pay the fine imposed to the airline, in case you are denied.
> 3. Approach a different counter or airline.

Note that it just takes 1 airline employee (+ their manager if they are around) to an arbitrarily refuse the passport to get denied boarding.

For example, the following passport got denied for boarding earlier this year because it was deemed "too wet" on right side by some airline employee, even though in practice it was almost dry and one could barely see any wet stain or discoloration, so it would have been in "almost new condition" by the time it is presented at the immigration agents after the flight:

[image]

Since then I stop taking the authorization to board for granted anymore and keep Anish's 3 options in mind (4th option, which is a more long term option: get two passports).