# Petty Stain on passport

Tags: indian-citizens, damaged-passports

[image]I have small stain on my passport first page and rest of passport is in good condition with no issues . Also i got the visa issued for schengen on the same passport . i dont even time to apply for new passport as there is no tatkaal scheme available in jammu so it will probably take like forever to get it reissued
can you guys have some feedback for me please

Comment: feedback on what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Slight stain on passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158293/slight-stain-on-passport)

Answer (score 5):

Passport get used and abused a lot; stains/shit happen.

As long as the ID pages and chips (if it has one) and the pages are relatively clean you should be OK.

And in your case, the visa is still readable you should also be OK.