# Why will ETIAS add some motivation for dual US/EU citizens not to use their US passports to fly to the EU?

Tags: us-citizens, dual-nationality, eu, eu-citizens, etias

I read on [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/158401/1810) by [phoog](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/19400/phoog):

> I routinely use different passports for different flights on the same booking (a US passport and an EU passport) because I am typically flying between the US and the EU.  Once ETIAS goes into operation, this will likely become even more common, as there will be additional motivation for dual US/EU citizens not to use their US passports to fly to the EU.

Why will ETIAS add some motivation for dual US/EU citizens not to use their US passports to fly to the EU?

---

ETIAS stands for European Travel Information and Authorization System. It is a completely electronic system which allows and keeps track of visitors from countries who do not need a visa to enter the Schengen Zone. From the end of 2022, all US citizens traveling to Europe for short-term stays will be obliged to have an ETIAS visa waiver with them before their trip.

Comment: (2020) ETIAS Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ) - ETIAS.COM [I have dual citizenship for an E.U. country (e.g. Italy, France, Germany, etc.) and for an ETIAS eligible country (e.g. USA, Canada, Australia), do I need an ETIAS?](https://etias.com/etias-frequently-asked-questions#collapseAlreadyHavePP): **No, you should use the passport of the E.U. or ETIAS member country to enter and exit Europe. You will not need an ETIAS if you travel using the passport of the E.U. member country.**

Comment: Since the **exact** questions for the ETIAS (introduction now planed for late 2022) application are not known (such as list of other citizenships), it is not reliably known if an application will be refused if you are also an EU Citizen. Note the usage of the word **should** in the answer to the appropriate FAQ. So either they have no objection of peaple wasting € 7 or that peaple will be using a bit of common sense when planning their travels.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you said it in your question -- people traveling on their US passports would need the ETIAS authorization beforehand to enter Europe. Traveling on their EU passport would presumably save that step (along with any associated fees).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that using the US passport would result in having to complete in the ETIAS  authorization process before the flight.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt what did you think then?  Some early materials even said that EU citizens would have to use their EU passports because they would be ineligible for ETIAS authorization even with a non-EU passport (similar to Canada's eTA).  They may have reconsidered that position, though, because I haven't seen this mentioned in more recent materials.

Comment: @phoog I try not to think when going through immigrations and customs: instead I try to follow whichever rules are in place. If I thought, then my reasoning would be that the EU hopefully has a way to link US passport IDs with EU passport IDs.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Why would you assume that? Countries are **not** required to recognize a second citizenship (local citizenship takes priority). Some countries even forbid the use of the second passport when entering or leaving.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That could be useful for a country to know when their citizens enter the country.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The burden of proof lies with the traveler. For the EU there is no immigration control for EU Citizens. You supply proof of citizenship and enter or leave (officially not even noted). For the US you **must** use your US Passport when entering.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yes this is why I try not to think when going through immigrations and customs and instead mindlessly follow whichever rules are in place.

Comment: @Frank Dernoncourt Why didn't you realise that using the US passport would result in having to complete in the ETIAS authorization process before the flight? You wrote it in your question...

Comment: @Traveller showing a US passport doesn't mean one is only a US citizen

Comment: @Frank Dernoncourt Of course not, but if the US passport is the one the traveller chooses to use, it’s logical that rules pertaining to that citizenship will apply.

Comment: @Traveller As mentioned above, I was hoping the EU had a way to link US passport IDs with EU passport IDs, so I don't think it's logical, just empirical.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt the EU has generally been very wary of the police-state implications of digital surveillance.  Having a database of foreign passports held by EU citizens would probably not get very far in any discussion of these new systems.  It's much simpler,  safer, and more secure to require any EU citizen who wants to be treated as such to show a passport or national ID card issued by an EU country.